# Display chosen string in variable given in php

Tags: php, laravel

I need to display a string for each info given in variable.

Example variable which contain string

```php
$sentence = "<audit><auLogNo></auLogNo><menuId></menuId><txnId></txnId><sortId></sortId><crLogNo>HTP1605809271</crLogNo><crResoDatetm>2016-08-15 10:03:26.0</crResoDatetm><showNewStartDate></showNewStartDate><endDatetime>2016-08-15 10:05:45.0</endDatetime><crGroupId>OSS</crGroupId><crFwdTo>7980</crFwdTo><crVendorRptno></crVendorRptno><crAction>01</crAction><crResolution>4G link status restored after YTL rebooting modem by remotely.</crResolution></audit>"
```

If I want to print `crLogNO` which string is `HTP1605809271`, what do I need to echo the `crLogNo` data in variable given ?

Example display data

> Log NO : HTP1605809271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `simplexml_load_string`

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($sentence, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Comment: but my string in $sentence does not contain xml? do i need to switch to xml?

Comment: put as is, just print dd at the end `dd($array['crLogNo']);` and you will see the answer `HTP1605809271`